# efficient query for many to many table

Tags: sql, linq

I'm writing a unit test of my mock-up repositoy. While the real repository lays on the linq2sql, the mock-up only use list of linq2sql objects. When it comes to the many to many tables, the efficency is rather low.

Here is the senario.

I have a many2many table which is tablePersonInCommunity, stores a CommunityID and a PersonID. And also a many2many table tablePersionInContact, stores a ContactID and a PersionID. The ContactID points to a entity of the Contact table. which have the following structure:

ContactID   int,
ContactType int(Business or Home),
Address1    string,
Address2    string,
...

Now, I wanna to get a record looks like this:
PersionID, BusinessContact, HomeContact

What is the most efficent solution? my simple test including 100 Persons' infomation caused a time-out when Im testing against the list mock-up.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer will be in making sure you have the right indexing strategy for your tables.

So... on your many-to-many table, have an index on (ContactID, PersonID), and another on (PersonID, ContactID), so that your query can cope with looking up people by contact or contacts by person.

Rob

Comment: Thank you. But I'm running unit test to the list-based mockups. There is no way to add index. I've used another algorithm in my code. Faster than before. Thank you all the same!